# Why I cannot change sa password using osql?

Tags: sql-server, windows, osql, sa

I got a laptop on which SQL Server Express is already installed. The server name is **SRH\SQLEXPRESS** and the version is **10.0.2531.0**. The operating system is Windows 7.

I can connect to it through Windows Authentication. But I would like to connect to it though `sa`. Since I dont know the password of `sa` so I want to reset it. I decided to change it using `osql`.

These are the steps I took to change the password of `sa`:

1. I opened command prompt (cmd) in Administrator mode.
2. I typed in `osql -S SRH\SQLEXPRESS -E` and press Enter key.
3. Then I get the **1>** prompt. I then typed in `sp_password null,
   'HseWork11', 'sa'` and press Enter key.
4. Then I get the **2>** prompt. I then typed in `GO` and press Enter
   key, But I get this error message:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Server SRH\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1 Cannot
>   alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have
>   permission.

Bummer.

To confirm that the login `sa` exist, I connect through Windows Authentication and run this statement `select * from sys.syslogins where name = 'sa'`. I got 1 row back so the login `sa` exist.

So why I cannot change `sa` password using `osql`? what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `sp_password`, have you tried using `ALTER LOGIN`, perhaps with the `UNLOCK` option? I use `sqlcmd` instead of `osql` - I don't actually know if that makes a difference.

In the command prompt:

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS
>1 ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = ‘whateveryouwant’ UNLOCK
>2 GO
>3 exit
```

These are obviously different commands, and I know that sometimes `ALTER LOGIN` has worked for me where `sp_password` has not.  I don't believe it's a cure-all, but it might be worth taking a look.

**Side Note:**

If this doesn't work, but you can still connect to SQL Server (you said you can, just not as SA), it might be worthwhile to run this query to see who **can** access SQL Server as an administrator.  Maybe you have a built-in account that was given that role...

```
USE Master
GO

SELECT
      P.Name
     ,P.Type_desc
     ,P.is_disabled
FROM sys.server_principals P
INNER JOIN sys.syslogins L
    ON L.SID = P.SID
WHERE P.Name NOT LIKE '#%'
AND L.SysAdmin = 1 
;
```

This will give you both SQL Server and Windows users who have the SysAdmin role.

**First Edit:**

You said that `is_disabled` is marked as `1` for the `SA` account after running this query.

Go back to your command prompt and try the following:

```
>1 ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE
>2 GO
>3 exit
```

Comment: I tried `ALTER LOGIN` using `sqlcmd` as you said but I get the same error message.  Then I ran your query and it returned 1 row: **Name** is `sa` , **Type_desc** is `SQL_LOGIN` and **is_disabled** is `1`. Why **is_disabled** is `1` and not `0`?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please try the solution I've added and let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: After enabling the login, you should be able to retry using the previous `ALTER LOGIN` command to change the password.

Comment: I tried `ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE` using `sqlcmd` as you said but I get the same error message.

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/937682/how-to-add-a-windows-user-to-the-sysadmin-fixed-server-role-in-sql-server-2005-as-a-failure-recovery-mechanism) and see if the steps listed there can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You might not be a System Administrator in SQL Server instance with your windows login. If you have system administrator permissions, you should be able to change the password of sa login.

Please refer 
[Wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-SA-Password-in-Sql-Server)

Note: [OSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx) is a discontinued feature, please use SQLCMD.

Comment: How to check if my windows login is a System Administrator in SQL Server?

Comment: @srh You already know it isn't, because you ran the query I suggested and your Windows account wasn't listed as one of the System Administrators.

Comment: @3BK oh I get it; that query has that filter `SysAdmin = 1` to only show system administrator logins

Comment: @Venu so all answers in http://www.wikihow.com/Reset-SA-Password-in-Sql-Server would not work for me since all those answers assume that the windows login is a System Administrator which is not true in my case

Comment: @srh, a non system administrator user cannot change the password of a system administrator account.